# Правописание суффиксов -ан-, -ян-, -ин-, -он-, -ён-, -ен-

Tags: орфография

Каковы правила правописание суффиксов -ан-, -ян-, -ин-, -он-, -ён-, -ен- в прилагательных и причастиях?

Answer (score 2):

### Правописание *-н-* и *-нн-* в прилагательных и причастиях

Чтобы правильно написать проблемное слово, можно воспользоваться алгоритмом:

1. Определить, входит ли оно в исключение.
2. От какой части речи образовано слово?
   А) от существительного:

   - Если к основе существительного прибавляется суффикс *-ственн (-ств-енн-)*, в прилагательном пишется две *н*: *дар* + *ственн* = *дарственный*.
   - Если основа существительного заканчивается на *н*, тогда в прилагательном пишется две *н*: ***стен***а + ***н*** = *сте**нн**ой*, ***камень*** + ***н*** = *каме**нн**ый*. NB! В словах *зеленый, поганый, пряный, румяный, свиной, синий, юный, фазаний, бараний, олений, тюлений* и др. суффикс *-н-* не прибавляется, поэтому они пишутся с одной *н*.
   - Если основа существительного заканчивается на *-мя*, то в прилагательном пишется две *н*: *времени (вре**мя**)* + *н* = *време**нн**ый*, *имени (и**мя**)* + *н* = *име**нн**ой*.
   - Если в прилагательном между *нн* есть беглый *е*, пишется две *н*: *искре**нн**ий* *(искрен**е**н)*.
   - Если к основе существительного прибавляется суффикс *-енн-* или *-онн-*, в прилагательном пишется две *н*: *утро* + *енн* = *утр**енн**ий*, *лекция* + *онн* = лекци**онн**ый.
   - Если к основе существительного прибавляется суффикс *-ан-*, *-ян-* или *-ин-*, в прилагательнном пишется одна *н*: *кожа* + *ан* = *кож**ан**ый*, *глина* + *ян* = *глин**ян**ый*, *гость* + *ин* = *гост**ин**ый*.

   Б) от глагола:

   - Если основа инфинитива (неопределенной формы) имеет суффикс *-ова-*, *-ева-*, *-ирова-*, в причастии пишется две *н*: *опер**ирова**ть* → *оперирова**нн**ый*.
   - Если причастие образовано от двувидового глагола, пишется две *н*: *казнё**нн**ый*.
   - Если глагол совершенного вида, в причастии пишется две *н*: *застроить* (что **с**делать?) → *застрое**нн**ый*. (Если у глагола есть приставка, в причастии пишется две *н*.)
   - Если у причастия есть зависимое слово, пишется две *н*: *сверлё**нн**ая **(чем?)** дрелью*.

**Исключения**:

- прилагательные: *ветре**н**ый, стекля**нн**ый, оловя**нн**ый, деревя**нн**ый*;
- причастия: *кованый*, *златокованый*, но *подкованный, кованный молотом*; *жёваный*, *жёваный-пережёваный*, но *изжёванный, жёванный медленно*; *клёваный*, но *раненый, крещёный, смышлёный, считаный ("малое количество"), исклёванный, клёванный птицами*; *желанный, священный, неожиданный, неслыханный, невиданный, нежданный, негаданный, недрема́нный, нечаянный, отчаянный, несчитанный, нетленный, окаянный, деланный, жеманный, чванный, чеканный, медленный, штукатуренный, обещанный, лелеянный, контуженый* (допуст. *контуженный*, если обр. от гл. сов. в.), *конченый, названый (брат), посажёный (мать, отец), Прощёное воскресенье, прощёный (день, колодец)* и др.